# How to create a word checker with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to develop a simple script that reads the words of a string, and compare with a dictionary `.txt` or an Array of correct words.

The format of my string is like this:

```
<data>
    <value>Testy</value>
</data>
<data>
    <value>Helllo wordi</value>
</data>
<data>
    <value>Gren Titl</value>
</data>
 <data>
    <value>Nanme</value>
</data>
```

He can only apply the fix on the words that you have within the `<value>` tag.
What he would have me return should be the same structure with the words corrected. This Form.

```
<data>
    <value>Test</value>
</data>
<data>
    <value>Hello word</value>
</data>
<data>
    <value>Green Title</value>
</data>
 <data>
    <value>Name</value>
</data>
```

Is it possible to do this? If yes how can I be doing in my code? Example?

**[DEMO CODE](http://jsfiddle.net/JoaoFelipePego/UpYgA/5/)**

```
$('button').click(function () {
    var code = $('textarea[name=message]').val();

    if ($('#output').length < 1) {
        $("body").append('<h2>Output</h2><textarea id="output" rows="10" cols="100"></textarea>');
    }



    $('#output').val(code);
});
```

*My English is bad I hope my question has been clear and can be understood by you.*

Comment: Typically, I wouldn't recommend resources or link to 3rd party plugins to reach these goals unless you were previously using them, but you're obviously put forth enough effort to try and identify how to perform this. I would recommend [using the jQuery spell check plugin](http://javascriptspellcheck.com/jquery-spell-check/) which leverages ajax to hit the server and take advantage of PHP's `pspell` library at which to make a comparison against.

Comment: Hi, u mean Textfile.txt, right? I think this wont work in a browser u cant load the file on the client, maybe on the server but fileaccess on website to server files is very my eyes.

Comment: @Ipad @ Ohgodwhy I am developing a local application (offline). Because it will not have access to any server.

Answer (score 1):

i would say that if you have the dictionary you can use :

```
$("value").onkeydown(function() {
    var testVal = $(this).text();
    if ($.inArray(testVal, YourDictionaryArray) > -1) {
        //handle if word is in dict
    } else {
        //handle word not in dict..
    }
});
```

Comment: I need it to do the verification process when I click the button. would have to change the onkeydown event to onlick?

Comment: @user3743128 http://jsfiddle.net/UpYgA/6/ look at my edit, it wont work because i dont have the words array in there, but if you add it, it will work :)

Comment: Inside the "if" go for the array of certain words? ("Hello", "Green" ...) and the "else" I put the wrong? ("Helllo''," Gren "...) it will automatically replace words for the right or need to cite something?